# How to pass parameters to constructor when creating an array of objects using for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

```cpp
class Student
{
    int rollNo;
    string name;

    public:
        Student(int id_of_student, string name_of_student)
        {
            rollNo = id_of_student;
            name = name_of_student;
        }
        void getStudentData()
        {
            cout<<"The name of the student with roll No. "<<rollNo<<" is "<<name<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Student *ptr = new Student[30]; // Error: no default constructor exists for class "Student"

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way by which we can pass parameters to the constructor?

```sh
Error: no default constructor exists for class "Student"
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `new` instead of `std::vector`? For the latter the problem of creating objects with parameters is somewhat simpler - you can write a loop instead of very long initializer list.

Comment: In cases like this, aside from `emplace_back`, `new` or that C++11 initialization method, there's always the option of the good old `init`-Function.

Remove the parameters from the constructor (or supply them with default values), but also define an `init`function, which does the same thing.
Then you can initialize the objects after having allocated the object.
Even in a loop if you want.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

> ::(optional) new (placement_params)(optional) ( type ) initializer(optional)

> If initializer is a brace-enclosed list of arguments, the array is aggregate-initialized. (since C++11)

You can use optional aggregate initializer like this:

```
Student *ptr = new Student[3]{{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}};
```

however it is not very comfortable if you have many students (like 30 in your example).

Comment: Well, I would just go for `std::vector<Student> vec;` (followed by `reserve` to avoid memory reallocs) and then in the loop `vec.push_back(Student(i, "whatever"));`. But you asked about `operator new`, so I leave this example just for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `std::vector` if I were you. However, if you prefer to stick to `array`, here is how I would have done it with `array` (and below it the `std::vector` example)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Student
{
    int rollNo;
    string name;

    public:
        Student(int id_of_student, string name_of_student)
        {
            rollNo = id_of_student;
            name = name_of_student;
        }
        void getStudentData()
        {
            cout<<"The name of the student with roll No. "<<rollNo<<" is "<<name<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
       //Student *ptr = new Student[30]; // Error: no default constructor exists for class "Student"
    Student *array[30];
    //allocates 30 objects
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 30 ; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new Student(i, "Name Array" + std::to_string(i));
    }
    //usage
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 30 ; i++)
    {
        array[i]->getStudentData();
    }

    // freeing the 10 objects
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 30 ; i++)
    {
        delete array[i];
    }

       // you may also use std::vector
    std::vector<Student> arr;
    //reserve for 30 objects
    arr.reserve(30);
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 30 ; i++)
    {
        arr.push_back( Student(i, "Name vector" + std::to_string(i))) ;
    }
    // usage
    for (Student stu: arr)
    {
        stu.getStudentData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a vector of pointers is unnecessary, you can just use a vector of `Student` objects

Comment: Done !! Thanks for you review again :)

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to do as you ask is to use `std::vector`

```
std::vector<Student> students;
//This is optional, it prevents multiple reallocations, which is nice
students.reserve(30);
students.emplace_back(id, name);
students.push_back(Student(id, name));
```

However, you may consider just adding a default constructor. It would be up to you to know whether the object was initialized or not (I strongly recommend not adding a member like `bool is_initialized`, in case you might be tempted to)